# How to find out the total number of extensions/apps in a given category?

Tags: chrome-web-store

I need to find out how many Chrome extensions currently exist in the [Developer Tools category](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/ext/11-web-development) in the Chrome Web Store.

In its original design, the store used to show the number of extensions/apps in each category. But the new design doesn't seem to have this information anywhere... Is there any way I can find out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is going to be an easy task. If you view the [Developer Tools Catagory](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/ext/11-web-development) source code. You will notice that the store's "heavy lifting" is implemented in https://chrome.google.com/webstore/static/1367528764/wall/js/webstore.js which is a minimized javascript application that is quite extensive. One way to get the desired information would be to reverse engineer this javascript application until you discover just how google queries/loads the list. Once this is accomplished you should be able to query google and retrieve a list yourself then programmatically count the results.
I hope there is a simpler solution for this otherwise good luck!